# Run multiple scripts one after another in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to run three scripts one after the other.  One requires a user to input a file.  The scripts all run individually, and when I combine some with **&&** they work, but when I try to combine all three, it fails. They need each other to work, so it should go *script1.sh -> script2.sh -> script3.pl*.

1. *script1.sh* needs 2 files inputted
2. *script2.sh* needs to output a *.csv*
3. *script3.pl* runs on the *.csv* created and needs an input that I want to prompt the user for.

Each takes a long time to run, so I'm also trying to have them run in the background with `nohup`. They run individually as follows:

```
script1.sh file1 file2

script2.sh > file.csv

script3.pl --input answer
```

I have tried using the following;

```
echo -n "Question?  "
read answer
nohup script1.sh $1 $2 && script2.sh > file.csv && script3.pl --input $answer &
```

It will work with the question, *script2.sh*, and *script3.pl*, but when I had *script1.sh* it wont work. *Script1.sh* and *script2.sh* combined will also work, but I am trying to combine all of three.

Comment: Did you try saving all 3 lines in a single shell script say `combined.sh` and then executing it with `nohup combined.sh &`?

Comment: I would still need to be able to ask the question to be inputed into script3.pl

Comment: But it seems like you can ask the question right at the top? Why not run it using `read -p "Question?" answer` and then `nohup combined.sh file1 file2 $answer &`?

Comment: Does this work without `nohup`?  That could complicate things; you ideally want to run that whole chain of commands through `nohup`, not just `script1.sh $1 $2`.  Another thought is that you're using `&&` which [short circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) when a command exits with a failure code. Try semi-colon (`;`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
read -p "Question?  " answer ; \
nohup script1.sh file1 file2    && \
nohup script2.sh > file.csv     && \
nohup script3.pl --input $answer &
```

Comment: I think that the shell that runs the commands above is itself not protected from SIGHUP. So even though `script1.sh` will not be stopped by SIGHUP if you logout while it is executing, the shell that needs to run `script2.sh` and `script3.sh` will exit... and therefore not run them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a combined script like this - save as `combined`:

```
#!/bin/bash
script1.sh file1 file2
script2.sh > file.csv
script3.pl --input "$1"
```

Then you can run:

```
nohup ./combined "answer" &
```